# Show that sequence of composition of holomorphic functions is uniformly convergent

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:B(0,1)\rightarrow B(0,r)$ where $r\in(0,1)$ be a holomorphic function such that $f(0)=0$.

Let $f_1:=f, f_{n+1}:=f \circ f_n, n=1,2,\dots$

Show that sequence $(f_n)$ is uniformly convergent in $B(0,1)$ to a function identically equal to $0$.

To be honest, I have no idea how can I even start this. Maybe people smarter than me can throw some input on this topic... Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g:B(0,1)\to\mathbb{C}$ be given by $g(z)=f(z)/z$. By assumption on $f$, the function $g$ is well defined and holomorphic (it has a removable singularity at $0$). It is possible to use the maximum principle and show that$$\max_{z\in B(0,1)}|g(z)|\leq r.$$Hence, for every $z$ we have $|f(z)|\leq r\cdot |z|$.

Comment: Shouldnt it be $|f(z)|\leq |r\cdot z|$?